# how to correctly limit number of goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine, limiting

I'm getting in 'stdin' lines of URL's like: 
$ echo -e 'https://golang.org\nhttps://godoc.org\nhttps://golang.org' | go run 1.go .
The task is to get from each WEB-page number of word "Go". But I'm not allowed to start more than 5 goroutines and can use only standard library 
Here is my code:

```
    package main

    import (
      "fmt"
      "net/http"
      "bufio"
      "os"
      "regexp"
      "io/ioutil"
      "time"
    )

func worker(id int, jobs<-chan string, results chan<-int) {
  t0 := time.Now()
  for url := range jobs {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("problem while opening url", url)
      results<-0
      //continue
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    html, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
      continue
    }
    regExp:= regexp.MustCompile("Go")
    matches := regExp.FindAllStringIndex(string(html), -1)
    t1 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Count for", url, ":", len(matches), "Elapsed time:", 
t1.Sub(t0),  "works id", id)
    results<-len(matches)
  }
}

func main(){
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  jobs := make(chan string, 100)
  results := make(chan int, 100)
  t0 := time.Now()
  for w:= 0; w<5; w++{
    go worker(w, jobs, results)
  }
  var tasks int = 0
  res := 0
  for scanner.Scan() {
      jobs <- scanner.Text()
      tasks ++
  }
  close(jobs)
  for a := 1; a <= tasks; a++ {
    res+=<-results
  }
  close(results)
  t2 := time.Now()
  fmt.Println("Total:",res, "Elapsed total time:", t2.Sub(t0) );
}
```

I thought it works until I passed more than 5 URL (one of them was incorrect) to stdin. The output was:

```
 goroutine 9 [running]:
 panic ...
```

Obviously, extra goroutnes have been started. How to fix it? May be there are more convenient way to limit number of goroutines?

Comment: Why are you trying to limit goroutines, and why do you think it's a problem? You start 5 of your own, that's really all you need to control.

Comment: @JimB No more than 5 goroutines - that was a task

Comment: But you're making http requests which couldn't be done without launching goroutines, and the runtime needs some to work too. Not to mention the goroutine id has nothing to do with how many are actually running, goroutines are created and destroyed al the time.

Answer (score 1):

> goroutine 9 [running]:

Some goroutines are started by the runtime, and by web fetches.

Looking at your code, you only started 5 goroutines.

If you really want to know how many go routines you are running use [runtime.Numgoroutine](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumGoroutine)